# Impact of Changing Server role on underlying applications

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, minrole

I feel a need to change server role from Front-end to Application. Would it  have any impact on underlying running Applications?

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't.  You should be able to switch from App to Web with little issues.  You will need to start the APP services and change your DNS entry to point to the new WFE.  Other than that, there really is not much difference between the two.  The APP server runs application services, and the WFE handles all the web traffic.  These are interchangeable.  You will need to start/stop services on each server depending on the roles you want the servers to have.

Answer (score 0):

It will cause the issue if you are using one of the following Services

- Access Services
- Access Services 2010
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service
- PerformancePoint Service
- Visio Graphics Service

These services are associated with FE role, if you try to start it on Application Role server then it will be stopped. But if you go to the Custom MinRole then everything will work.

Converting role from one to other is not a major deal, but make sure you do it off hours as it will cause little interruption. Other than that you will be ok.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/description-of-minrole-and-associated-services-in-sharepoint-server-2016

Comment: But  going to 'Custom' role may not help me with my main problem because it doesn't run Project Server Application Service.
My main problem is, I am not able to create Project Server site collection. It shows the error 'Service Application not found'. So I think changing server role from 'Front-end' to 'Application' might help me out..